# Delivering a file instead of wordpress page

Tags: plugins, attachments

I'm trying to make a page where a user provides an ID of a attachment and the site will set the headers and deliver that file instead of a 404 page. so /download/1754 would lookup the attachment with that Id and output it for viewing/download depending on the file type.

I just can't think of a wordpress friendly way to do this from inside a plugin. I considered using add_rewrite_rule but couldn't see a good way around it, also considered checking $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] to deliver the content before any HTML but then I'd have to stop the page from rendering a 404 and I was not sure of a Wordpress friendly way to do this.

My current idea was to have my plugin make a download page, assign a template and have that template run the logic instead of my plugin class. while I have used this before for another situation it was very messy as I had to write a lot of code to force users to be unable to update or edit the file and recreate/delete it on activation.deactivation. so ideally I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: Have a look at the `template_redirect` action - http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect. This action will allow you to check whatever you want, such as `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, and if necessary redirect the user using `wp_safe_redirect()`.  Have a bash, if you struggle update your questions with your results and we can help more :)

Comment: @DavidGard There's [`wp_get_referer()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_get_referer/) for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right path with a rewrite rule. If you're just delivering a file, you can hook an early action, check if a download was requested, then output the file and exit before WordPress ever gets to the stage of querying the database and deciding the request is a 404.

```
// add the download ID query var which we'll set in the rewrite rule
function wpd_query_var( $query_vars ){
    $query_vars[] = 'download_id';
    return $query_vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpd_query_var' );

// add rewrite rule
function wpd_rewrite(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'download/([0-9]+)/?$',
        'index.php?download_id=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpd_rewrite' );

// check for download_id and output the file
function wpd_request( $wp ){
    if( array_key_exists( 'download_id', $wp->query_vars ) ) {
        // output your headers and file here
        // ID is in $wp->query_vars['download_id']
        // then exit to halt any further execution
        exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'parse_query', 'wpd_request' );
```

Comment: You have to flush rules after adding or changing them. normally you'd do that on plugin activation/deactivation, but you can also just visit the permalinks settings page.

Comment: I already have the code for auto flushing git on plugin activation and have tried it manually repeatedly. it's picking up a matched query_of 'attachment=3F8750942A' with the code being the test code I entered in the URL. Annoyingly this is probably the simplest use of rewrite rules I've done and obviously this is the one that's a pain.

Comment: oops, a couple of typos, sorry. forgot to `return $query_vars`, and the correct hook is `parse_query`.

Comment: I'd already fixed those previously. Seems once again it is an issue with wordpress, add_rewrite_rule not allowing an $ at the end where as add_rewrite_rules does allow it.

Comment: I've tested in twentyfourteen and it's working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following example, for image attachments:

```
add_action( 'init', function()
{                                                               
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'download', EP_ROOT );
    add_action( 'template_redirect', function()
    {
        if ( $pid = get_query_var( 'download' ) ) 
        {
            $found = false;
            if( $file = wp_get_attachment_image_src( absint( $pid ), 'full' ) )
            {
                $found = true;
                header( "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . basename( $file[0] ) );
                readfile( $file[0] );
                exit();
            }
            if( ! $found )
                wp_die( __( 'Image file not found!' ) );
        }
    } );   
} );
```

where you might have to adjust the headers to your needs.

Re-generate your rewrite rules and then you should be able to download the image attachments from:

```
http://example.tld/download/123/
```

There are much better scripts out there, compared to this simple demo, but it seems to work on my install. Check for example out [this blog](http://www.media-division.com/the-right-way-to-handle-file-downloads-in-php/), it seems to have some interesting ideas on how to handle large files.

Hopefully you can modify it to your needs.

Comment: The link is great. I hope you move some of the suggestions from there to here as well. Useful info that should be doubled to not go away :)

Comment: Yes there are plenty of useful information on that blog post (ps: this blog is unrelated to myself). I sometimes wish SE would allow attachments to answers or keep a service like the WayBackMachine ... hey let me check, ... found the archived blog post [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20150103164628/http://www.media-division.com/the-right-way-to-handle-file-downloads-in-php/) ... just in case ;-)