# Rewritten URL not loading WordPress environment

Tags: rewrite-rules, paths, wp-load.php

I have a page that I am sending users directly to so I can serve them a PDF dynamically created using the FPDF library. Since I'm sending them directly to the file which generates the PDF, I'm rewriting the URL. In the original file I use `require_once('wp-load.php')` with the correct path in order to load the WordPress environment. It loads perfectly fine and spits out the PDF when I go to `website/path/to/file.php?p=foo&q=bar` but when I go to `website/rewritten?p=foo&q=bar` the `require_once()` function is breaking.

I can tell that my rewrite rule is working properly because when I add debug messages to the file, they are printed when I go to `website/rewritten?p=foo&q=bar` and using `dirname(__FILE__)` returns the path of the actual file not the template.

Do I need to change the require path or something to load WordPress properly? I can't seem to figure it out no matter what I try.

Comment: you can handle everything within WordPress and avoid this issue, [see this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/176043/delivering-a-file-instead-of-wordpress-page).

Comment: @Milo Sorry, I think I phrased it poorly. I'm not actually serving them a PDF file that exists on the server. I'm sending them to a page which creates a PDF in browser via some PHP which can then be saved/printed. It's actually the FPDF library if that has any bearing on the situation. I'll update my question to reflect that. I'm not sure if your solution would be applicable in this case but I can try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is wondering I figured it out. Since I was hosting my WordPress site on a [Chassis](http://docs.chassis.io/en/latest/) server, the path I needed to use in my `require` statement was different than the actual path on my machine.